# Symfony - why "There is no extension able to load the configuration for "when@dev" "

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm in deep over my head here trying to move into symfony flex finally. I'm following along with the symfonycast here (https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4-upgrade/flex-alive#play) moving step-by-step but I get an error where he has none and was wondering if I could get a hint as to where I've gone wrong.

upon running php bin/console I am hit by:

In FileLoader.php line 180:

There is no extension able to load the configuration for "when@dev" (in "/Users/mattias/Documents/www/webtools/config/package
s/monolog.yaml"). Looked for namespace "when@dev", found ""doctrine_cache", "doctrine", "fos_user", "sensio_framework_extra",
"monolog", "swiftmailer", "framework", "twig", "security"" in /Users/mattias/Documents/www/webtools/config/packages/monolog.
yaml (which is loaded in resource "/Users/mattias/Documents/www/webtools/config/packages/monolog.yaml").

In YamlFileLoader.php line 722:

There is no extension able to load the configuration for "when@dev" (in "/Users/mattias/Documents/www/webtools/config/package
s/monolog.yaml"). Looked for namespace "when@dev", found ""doctrine_cache", "doctrine", "fos_user", "sensio_framework_extra",
"monolog", "swiftmailer", "framework", "twig", "security"".

If I remove the when@dev from the monolog.yml file the same error appears with the next section instead (the when@test) so I assume there is some main wireing that hasn't been done etc.

I've googled the error but I seem to be the first one

It seems as though I've ended up with monolog config for sym 5 so I wonder whether that tutorial is inaccurate in one of the composer directives. I might need to restrict some component to an earlier version when using it these days?

Here's my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "a/b",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
            "App\\": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\AppBundle\\": "tests/AppBundle",
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "jquery/jquery",
                "version": "1.11.1",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js",
                    "type": "file"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.1",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
        "symfony/console": "^4.0",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.19",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^4.0",
        "symfony/lts": "^4@dev",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/yaml": "^4.0",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/dotenv": "^4.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "symfony/flex": true
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "id": "",
            "allow-contrib": false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like you skipped a step. I forget which component is responsible, but one of your symfony components (guessing framework-bundle) needs to be upgraded.

Comment: Acording to the tag, you are in sf4, right? Then no cookie for you, as that feature was [introduced in 5.3](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-configure-multiple-environments-in-a-single-file).

Comment: Yes @msg that's what omeone else also told me... though I don't know how that happened, I'll paste my compser.json above, I'm not sure which of those require's gave me a much too recent version of monolog...

Answer (score 0):

The configuration is not handled by the bundle (monolog in this case), but by flex itself.

After package installation it runs "recipes" that take care of creating configuration, assets, etc. You can find the recipe for the monolog version [here](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/tree/main/symfony/monolog-bundle/3.1). There's no `when@` directive to be found until 3.7 but `composer.json` declares `^3.1.0`.
Use `composer show symfony/monolog-bundle` to see what version is *installed*, but I doubt there will be a problem in the version resolution. You can try to nuke `vendor/` and reinstall all packages.

The easiest way to go about it is to delete `config/packages/monolog.yaml`. since you *should* have your old configuration under `confib/packages/{dev,prod,test}/monolog.yaml` everything *should* continue working. If that's not the case you can always reinstall the recipe with `composer recipes:install symfony/monolog-bundle --force` to bring it back.

As for the tutorial itself, on a brief glance everything *seems* okay so far.

And keep in mind that the ability to parse `when` directives comes from `framework-bundle` >= 5.3. If you plan to upgrade all the way up you might want to reinstall recipes to pull in the latests configs (or maybe use `composer recipes:update` for an interactive, git-based update). Having all configs in one file is only a matter of convenience if the changes are small per environment, but everything will work just the same.